# How to make condition in treemap with red as negative value and green as positive value?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, treemap

Here is my code, my results seem wrong where I circled, the result is positive values ​​are green, red is negative value, only 2 color scale is green and red

How do I fix it I'd love your help

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Timestamp":['14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022',
        '14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022',
        '14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022',
        '14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022',
        '14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022'],
        "Name":['Binance','OKX','Kucoin','Houbi','FTX','Bitfinex','Bitmex','Bittrex','CoinList','BNB_US','MEXC','Crypto','Gate','Bitstamp','FTX_US','Coinbase',
        'Binance','OKX','Kucoin','Houbi','FTX','Bitfinex','Bitmex','Bittrex','CoinList','BNB_US','MEXC','Crypto','Gate','Bitstamp','FTX_US','Coinbase',
        'Binance','OKX','Kucoin','Houbi','FTX','Bitfinex','Bitmex','Bittrex','CoinList','BNB_US','MEXC','Crypto','Gate','Bitstamp','FTX_US','Coinbase'],

        "Stablecoin":['USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT',
        'USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC',
        'BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD'],

        "Value_USDT":[7.44,6.54,5.45,3,2,1.45,3,2,1,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,
        7,6,5,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,
        10.08,0,5,0,7,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,4,0,0,2],
        'percentage':[7.87,6.78,-5.08,-0.9,2.87,1.87,-3.78,2.87,1.6,3.67,-2.4,1.43,1.34,2.23,1.34,2.43,
        7.78,6.43,5.43,3.45,2,1,3,2,-1.98,3,2,-1.76,1,2,1,2,
        10.08,0.09,-5,0.07,7,0.76,0.67,0.87,0.56,-3,2,-1.65,4,0.56,0.65,2]
    }
)
data['all'] = 'all'
def set_colorscale(z, colors):
    if len(colors) !=3:
        raise ValueError("")
    neg=z[np.where(z<0)]
    pos=z[np.where(z>0)]    
    a, c = neg.min(), neg.max()
    d, b = pos.min(), pos.max()
    bvals= [a, c/2, d/2, b]
    nvals = [(v-bvals[0])/(bvals[-1]-bvals[0]) for v in bvals] 
    dcolorscale = []
    for k in range(len(colors)):
        dcolorscale.extend([[nvals[k], colors[k]], [nvals[k+1], colors[k]]])
    return dcolorscale  

z = np.array(data['percentage'])
pl_colorscale= set_colorscale(z, ["#DC3714", "#C0C0C0", "#19BD1B"])
fig = px.treemap(data, path=[px.Constant('all'),'Stablecoin','Name','percentage'],values='Value_USDT')
fig.update_traces(textinfo = "label",textposition="middle center",hovertemplate='labels=%{label}<br>value=%{value}<extra></extra>')
fig.update_traces(hovertext=['percentage'])
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(
    colors=data['percentage'],
    colorscale=pl_colorscale,
    showscale=True
))
fig.update_layout(width=1400, height=550,title="TreeMap stablecoin")
fig.show()
```

Here is my code, I don’t know how to make the positive value green , seems in my code the result is wrong

[how to fix negative value to red color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2pDt.png)

Comment: the number you print in the middle of the box is `Value_USDT` but the one used to calculate the color is `percentaage`. Use either one or the other but don't mix them. For Binance you can see in the hover that value is 7.44 but the number in the middle of the box is 7.87.  Should the number you print be percentage or Value_USDT?

Comment: The value that I want to print is percentage and the color condition is also percentage, what should I do to change it

Comment: you change `fig = px.treemap(data, path=[px.Constant('all'),'Stablecoin','Name','percentage'],values='Value_USDT')`  to `fig = px.treemap(data, path=[px.Constant('all'),'Stablecoin','Name','percentage'],values='percentage')`. Did you create this code?

Comment: ohh OMG thank you very much this all correct My mistake is silly

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set condition for `percentage` and use it for color mapping. Please refer below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Timestamp":['14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022',
        '14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022',
        '14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022',
        '14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022',
        '14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022','14-02-2022'],
        "Name":['Binance','OKX','Kucoin','Houbi','FTX','Bitfinex','Bitmex','Bittrex','CoinList','BNB_US','MEXC','Crypto','Gate','Bitstamp','FTX_US','Coinbase',
        'Binance','OKX','Kucoin','Houbi','FTX','Bitfinex','Bitmex','Bittrex','CoinList','BNB_US','MEXC','Crypto','Gate','Bitstamp','FTX_US','Coinbase',
        'Binance','OKX','Kucoin','Houbi','FTX','Bitfinex','Bitmex','Bittrex','CoinList','BNB_US','MEXC','Crypto','Gate','Bitstamp','FTX_US','Coinbase'],

        "Stablecoin":['USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT','USDT',
        'USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC','USDC',
        'BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD','BUSD'],

        "Value_USDT":[7.44,6.54,5.45,3,2,1.45,3,2,1,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,
        7,6,5,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,
        10.08,0,5,0,7,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,4,0,0,2],
        'percentage':[7.87,6.78,-5.08,-0.9,2.87,1.87,-3.78,2.87,1.6,3.67,-2.4,1.43,1.34,2.23,1.34,2.43,
        7.78,6.43,5.43,3.45,2,1,3,2,-1.98,3,2,-1.76,1,2,1,2,
        10.08,0.09,-5,0.07,7,0.76,0.67,0.87,0.56,-3,2,-1.65,4,0.56,0.65,2]
    }
)
data['all'] = 'all'
condition = [data['percentage']>0,
            data['percentage']==0,
            data['percentage']<0]

choices = ['A','B','C']
data['Condition'] = np.select(condition,choices,default='D')

fig = px.treemap(data, path=[px.Constant('all'),'Stablecoin','Name','percentage'],
                 values='Value_USDT',color='Condition',
                 color_discrete_map={'(?)':'black','A':"#19BD1B", 
                                     'B':"#C0C0C0",
                                     'C':"#DC3714",
                                     'D':'#AB63FA'})
fig.update_traces(textinfo = "label",
                  textposition="middle center",
                  hovertemplate='labels=%{label}<br>value=%{value}<extra></extra>')
fig.update_traces(hovertext=['percentage'])
fig.update_layout(width=1400, height=550,title="TreeMap stablecoin")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, I made a mistake somewhere in my code

Comment: Is it possible to look at the time option on the chart treemap?

Comment: @ĐỗVănThắng: Nhắn cho mình qua Zalo 0903451501 nhé. Trả lời trên này hơi dài ấy.